# prevent fgetcsv() from breaking on \n inside enclosure

Tags: php

My file is like this

```
row 1: 1,2,3,4
row 2: bob,larry,jill, "sue 
she is a great girl"
row3 3:tom, fred, jack, billy
```

when I use  fgetcsv($handle,0,',','"') it breaks up row 2 into two separate rows because column 4 has a \n in it. The people who are giving me these csv are using excel to do it and excel is only enclosing with double quotes when there is a special character.

How can I write fgetcsv() so that it does not break on \n that are inside of double quotes? I am writing very heavy PHP and am parsing sometimes millions of rows so my solution has to be memory and time efficient. It just seems to me that I must be using fgetcsv wrong because it should obviously not be breaking on an enclosed \n.

Comment: not answering your question but check this out https://csv.thephpleague.com/

Comment: @Fahmi hahaha I mistead that website as "The PHP Plague" hehe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the code:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
        print_r($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

and the test.csv:

```
1,2,3,4
bob,larry,jill, "sue 
she is a great girl"
tom, fred, jack, billy
```

the result is as excepted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => bob
    [1] => larry
    [2] => jill
    [3] => sue 
she is a great girl
)
Array
(
    [0] => tom
    [1] =>  fred
    [2] =>  jack
    [3] =>  billy
)
```

Comment: OK I guess it the length parameter. Thanks I just overlooked that completely.

Answer (score -1):

your file must be:

```
1,2,3,4
bob,larry,jill, "sue 
she is a great girl"
tom, fred, jack, billy
```

without \n in it

Comment: That's how it is. It's a \n  that looks like what you said is should look like. And it breaks on the \n even though its enclosed.